# Given a convex quadrilateral(ABCD) decide if D is inside the circumcircle of triangle ABC

Tags: geometry

`Given a convex quadrilateral(ABCD) decide if D is inside the circumcircle of triangle ABC`

How do I approach this, I have no idea how to solve this one ? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare $\angle ABC+\angle ADC $ with $180^\circ $

Comment: and what happens if the `∠ABC+∠ADC` is less,equal or bigger ?

Comment: Since this is for a C++ program, a "robust" program needs to check that you have a convex quadrilateral.  This requires checking no 3 of the 4 points are collinear and that it is simple; i.e. sides intersect only at the vertices and then check for convexity by making certain no angle exceeds 180 degrees.  (The angle check is a bit tricky; you can't just use arccos.)  Since you then must have functions to intersect lines, you might just as easily compute the equation of the circum circle and then the test for D inside or outside is "easy".

Answer (score 0):

Opposite angles of a cyclic quadrilateral add up to $180^\circ$. So if $D$ is exactly on the circumcircle of triangle $ABC$, $\angle CDA + \angle ABC = 180^\circ$. Now what happens if $D$ is inside or outside the circumcircle?

Comment: @CioroianuDenis: My question wasn't a request for information, it was a hint!

Comment: Ummm...not quite. Perhaps you should draw a picture.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the following:-

(1) The equation of the circum-circle of ABC is known and is $x^2 + y^2 + Px + Qy + R = 0$ with $P, Q, R$ known.

(2) The co-ordinates of $D$ is also known and is $(h, k)$.

Find $T = (h)^2 + (k)^2 + P(h) + Q(k) + R$.

If $T \gt 0$, then $D$ is outside.

If $T \lt 0$, then $D$ is inside.